# How to mutate across a dataframe to filter based on a two conditional cut-off value in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, tidyverse

I am trying to `mutate` `across` a dataframe to `filter` based on a two conditions in R via `tidyverse` library. I would like to calculate and consider the entities passing with a cut-off value of `(<= -0.5 and >= 0.5)` in at least 3 out of 5 samples or columns (S1 to S5) (basically, I would like to obtain 3/4 percentage of entities passing this cut-off value). I am doing this in two different steps, is there a way to execute in the cut-off conditions in the same step? I have provided the example datasets and code. Please assist.

```
library(tidyverse)

sample_data <- data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
  row.names = c("Entity_1","Entity_2","Entity_3",
                "Entity_4","Entity_5","Entity_6","Entity_7","Entity_8",
                "Entity_9","Entity_10","Entity_11","Entity_12","Entity_13",
                "Entity_14","Entity_15"),
  `S 1` = c(0.883643926,0.248614376,0.518091486,
            0.535221236,0.415450436,-0.940323826,-0.723796576,
            -0.824290276,NA,-0.806255146,-0.747521326,NA,3.20247786,1.10402434,
            1.005757776),
  `S 2` = c(1.005757776,1.005757776,4.51601548,3,
            7.78620408,-0.706674058,-0.572657338,-0.686018538,
            -0.514713298,-0.532390248,-0.462136378,-0.512892468,1,1.5,2.5),
  `S 3` = c(7.798089,9.2058061,5.5408169,
            1.52159119,2.63042701,NA,1.3857699,-0.152939869,-0.050295909,
            -0.337659179,-0.058902499,-0.072916919,-0.410700949,
            -0.079817359,-0.313859499),
  `S 4` = c(1.41324408,9.6038562,1.71087962,
            2.95921938,4.82199712,3.17140358,1.15931318,NA,1.58997338,
            4.76858598,NA,-0.002674678,-0.235496858,0.065630452,
            -0.175745228),
  `S 5` = c(-0.167945369,1.41324408,1.41324408,
            0.741171721,2.494610191,-0.532343489,-0.358607189,
            -0.442774239,-0.103589789,0.213156301,-0.022826199,-0.096645979,
            1.215920941,3.377354481,0.033402621)
)

## Entity passing <= -0.5
sample_data %>% 
  mutate(across(.fns = ~ . <= -0.5)) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Entity") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(prop = sum(c_across(starts_with("S")), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(prop >= 3)

## Entity passing >= 0.5
sample_data %>% 
  mutate(across(.fns = ~ . >= 0.5)) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Entity") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(prop = sum(c_across(starts_with("S")), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(prop >= 3)
```

Thank you,

Mohammed

Comment: How about `mutate(across(.fns = ~ . <= -0.5 | . >= 0.5))` ?

Comment: @tacoman your suggestions were helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    sample_data %>% 
      mutate(prop = rowSums(across(everything(), .fns = ~ . <= -0.5 | .>=0.5))) %>%
      filter(prop >=3)

               S 1        S 2         S 3         S 4        S 5 prop
Entity_1   0.8836439  1.0057578  7.79808900  1.41324408 -0.1679454    4
Entity_2   0.2486144  1.0057578  9.20580610  9.60385620  1.4132441    4
Entity_3   0.5180915  4.5160155  5.54081690  1.71087962  1.4132441    5
Entity_4   0.5352212  3.0000000  1.52159119  2.95921938  0.7411717    5
Entity_5   0.4154504  7.7862041  2.63042701  4.82199712  2.4946102    4
Entity_7  -0.7237966 -0.5726573  1.38576990  1.15931318 -0.3586072    4
Entity_10 -0.8062551 -0.5323902 -0.33765918  4.76858598  0.2131563    3
Entity_13  3.2024779  1.0000000 -0.41070095 -0.23549686  1.2159209    3
Entity_14  1.1040243  1.5000000 -0.07981736  0.06563045  3.3773545    3
```

this works for you ?